# Getting first and last created SObject id after instance split

Tags: apex, soql, salesforce-id

Production org recently went through instance split. Before instance split I was able to find out first id created for any sobject and last id created for any sobject by simply making a query(Created date order by desc or asc).

Now after instance split is there any way to get last id created for any sobject for the old instance and first id created after the instance split. Basically I want to do this so that I could create buckets of 50K ids and make multiple queries to fetch data that I need from massive data without hitting query timeout error. Any pointers would be much helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like the best approach would use `CreatedDate` and the timestamp of the split.

Comment: @Adrian Larson. Actually I don't know exact time. As per salesforce it was an activity of 2 hours. Production users were using the system so it might happen   that I might skip some records which were created by users at that time as soon as they got access to system. Thanks for reply.